# How to have a fixed value be replaced with NAs in SQL based on columns that DATE in their names

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a SQL query below where at the final table, I need to the query to go through and for every column that has the word "DATE" in the name, the query will go and find the value "1900-01-01" and replace it with NULL or NA value.

In the below I have simplified the column / query, I have 100s of date columns so can't individually list them

```
SELECT DISTINCT
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
col_date_1
col_date_2
col_date_99      
FROM "DATATABLE"

WHERE col1 = '2020'
WHERE col2 IS NOT null 
    AND col3 NOT IN ('criteria1', 'criteria2') 
    AND col3 LIKE '0510%' //but exclude '0510005000'
    AND NOT((col4= 'NA' AND col5 IN ('TX', 'XK', 'XT', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4', 'YR', 'ZH', 'ZI', 'ZJ')))
```

Comment: Hi - the SQL you’ve provided doesn’t seem to relate to your requirements in any way, it doesn’t mention 1900-01-01 and is a SELECT not an UPDATE; can you clarify? Also, what is the datatype of the columns you want to update?

Comment: I would just take the list of columns into excel, turn that into `nullif(col_name,'1900-01-01') as col_name,` using some string functions and then paste them back into the select query. You could also use that select query (without where clause) to create a view that can be later used just like your main table except you won't have to worry about handling that date over and over again

Comment: The larger question of why do you have `1900-01-01` in the first place and what you should/could do to fix the underlying cause still remains with you

Comment: hi the value "1900-01-01" is a value in the columns that have the word date in it. The column types of the "date" column is character. I am selecting columns from a database that I will pull into my Quarto markdown publication. In real life, I have 1,000s of columns and millions of rows so using excel is not an option.  Yes the larger and more interesting question is why 1900-01-01 is there in a first place but I don't have the power to change that right now. I am doing this transformation in R and it takes a long time so I'd rather use Snowflake to do the transformation for me